# Unable to attach to process for debugging - why does it happen?

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, process

I am developing an application in C using Visual Studio 2010 and was trying to debug it. Unfortunately I get an "Unable to attach." error which claims that my executable (which builds ok) is not running on 'NAME_OF_MY_MACHINE'.

Reading through other questions involving not being able to process suggested this might have something to do with privileges, however my problem persists even if I explicitly run VS as an Administrator.

If I run the compiled executable without trying to attach the debugger it presents output up to a point only then to spew out an access violation error.

After some time I discovered that when I run the application manually, let it pause and then try to attach to it, it gave me a bunch of 'Cannot find or open the PDB file' messages on the output related to dll's it loaded. Then going into Tools->Options->Debugging->Native->Load DLL Exports... fixes the problem.

Why might this behaviour be occurring?

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: I have found the way to remedy the problem but I don't know enough about what I've done to put it in down as an 'Answer'.
I noticed that when I run the application manually, let it pause and then try to attach to it, it gave me a bunch of 'Cannot find or open the PDB file' messages on the output related to dll's it loaded. Going into Tools->Options->Debugging->Native->Load DLL Exports... fixed the problem.

Comment: @user694733 - its a little difficult in this case as I am working on legacy code with bunch of custom libraries, custom makefile, a broken original VS project and a whole bunch of other sadness. It wasn't clear to me where the problem laid.

Comment: You don't need to give answer, but question should include all necessary information. If giving MCVE is near impossible, you should at least edit the question to include your workaround, as it might help someone to figure out the cause of the problem.